# IOS difference between subview and container view

Tags: ios, xcode, subview, uicontainerview

what is the difference between a subview and a container view. I have a piece of code that is successfully working by adding subview programmatically. But I want to be able to lay out the subview in the editor not in code. The only thing I could find was containerview. What is the difference and can they be used interchangeably.

Thanks.

Comment: A "subview" isn't really a thing.  It's a common term for a view that is a descendant of another view.  Similarly, "containerview" isn't a thing.  Again, it's just a common term for a view (usually a sub-class of ViewController) that contains other views (and usually provides services to those views)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use UIView when you already have a view and you do not need to have a dedicated view controller to build and handle interactions within it.

From the UIView help page:

UIView object claims a rectangular region of its enclosing superview (its parent in the view hierarchy) and is responsible for all drawing in that region ...

> Simplified structure: YourViewController ---(has)---> UIView

You use UIContainerView when you need to embed another view controller in the one that you already have. The embedded view controller is in charge of returning a view for the region that the UIViewContainer occupies. Therefore, your UIContainerView knows which view controller to use to render UIView inside the region it occupies.

From the UIContainerView help page:

Container View defines a region within a view controller's view subgraph that can include a child view controller.

> Simplified structure: YourViewController ---(has)---> SubViewContoller
>   ---(has)---> UIView

That SubViewController returns a view and handles its events.

Last if you want to learn how to layout subviews, i cannot explain that over here, so you might need to go through one of the tutorials. 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1